# How to export results as a PDF report?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using SonarQube 5.6.3. How can I create a SonarQube analysis details report as a PDF form, an excel report, or an html formatted report?

No plugin seems to be available for this.

I was unable to generate an html file using below configuration:

```
sonar.issuesReport.html.enable = true
sonar.issuesReport.html.location = c:\
sonar.issuesReport.html.name = sample
```

How can I export these details from SonarQube?

Answer (score 5):

For the sonar-maven-plugin it works the same. Just add these two properties to the pom file:

```
<project xmlns="...>
     ...
    <properties>
         <sonar.analysis.mode>preview</sonar.analysis.mode>
         <sonar.issuesReport.html.enable>true</sonar.issuesReport.html.enable>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

results will be in the target/sonar folder

Comment: Is this still valid for Community Edition Version 7.5?

Answer (score 4):

The Governance plugin allows to generate PDF reports. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Governance+plugin for more details. Please note that I work at SonarSource, the company developing this commercial plugin.

**EDIT**:

*Governance plugin* has been replaced by the [SonarQube Enterprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/) in versions 7.x.

Comment: Yeah, i got to see this Simon. I know about this.
But what about non-commercial plug-in or at least html report not getting generated :(

Comment: I do not see the plugin as available to install when I go to updatecenter/available page?

Comment: The Governance plugin supports only the Long-Term Support version (5.6.x) for the time being. A new release will be published in the next few weeks to support the next LTS version (6.7).

Comment: Is there any planned support for Microsoft's Power BI? 
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: That deserves a dedicated question. Still you could give a try to import ok JSON reports of SonarQube web api (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-data-sources/).

Answer (score 3):

To export results, you need to use paid version of SonarQube. This feature is not available for the free version of SonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to export the report in PDF (or customizable ODT) with the bitegarden report plugin for SonarQube https://www.bitegarden.com/sonarqube-report

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin, https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report
Based on your Sonarqube Edition, you can check the compatibility matrix and use the appropriate plugin version - https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report#compatibility-matrix. (This works only in Sonarqube-Community Edition)

Though this plugin does not provide the option to generate it as PDF, you can still generate it in Docx, xlsx, CSV, markdown, and text file formats

Answer (score -1):

To get html reports add these properties to your sonar.properties file

```
sonar.analysis.mode=preview 
sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
```

Comment: just by these parameters the report gets generated ? 
or u also tried with 

sonar.issuesReport.html.location = c:\

sonar.issuesReport.html.name = sample

and please confirm once which sonarQube version (i am sonarqube-5.6.3) u are using? I tried with all params like ( i mentioned), unable to generate the report.!

Comment: yes ,i got html reports(issues report).i tried with sonarqube 6.1. i didn't try with location to store these reports

Comment: This is not recommended to use these options in recent versions.

Comment: The plugin is deprecated. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin